# Hover traspasa las imágenes

Tags: html, css, hover, gallery

¡Hola! Estoy haciendo una galería de fotos usando HTML y CSS, y lo estoy haciendo tipo pinterest, en donde las fotos son de diferente tamaño y le agregué un hover para que a la hora de colocar el cursor encima de la imagen, presente un texto dependiendo de la imagen, sin embargo, estoy teniendo un problema.

El hover funciona, el problema es que el hover se traspasa de cada imagen, es decir, si pongo el cursor encima de una imagen, el hover es más largo que el largo de la imagen en sí.

Intenté ajustar el tamaño usando height en la clase capa e intenté cambiar el margin a ver si ese era el problema pero no logré nada. Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho, y si algo no se entiende por favor me dejan saber. ¡Gracias!

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  
}

.column
{
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.column .imagen{
  position: relative;
  
}

.imagen img{
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.capa{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h2{
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

.capa h2{
  color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size:30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imagen:hover .capa{
  height: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap');
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <header>
        Gallery pictures
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="imagen">
            <img src = "images/peonies.jpg" alt= "Peonies">
                <div class="capa">
                    <h2>Peonies</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="imagen">
            <img src="images/hydrangea.jpg" alt="Hydrangeas">
                <div class="capa">
                    <h2>Hydrangeas</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="imagen">
                <img src = "images/lily.jpg" alt= "Lilies">
                    <div class="capa">
                        <h2>Lilies</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="imagen">
                <img src = "images/orchids.jpg" alt= "Orchids">
                    <div class="capa">
                        <h2>Orchids</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="imagen">
                <img src = "images/tulips.jpg" alt= "Tulips">
                    <div class="capa">
                        <h2>Tulips</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/carnations.jpg" alt="Carnations">
                    <div class="capa">
                        <h2>Carnations</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="imagen">
                <img src = "images/daisies.jpg" alt= "Daisies">
                    <div class="capa">
                        <h2>Daisies</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="imagen">
                <img src="images/lavender.jpg" alt="Lavender">
                    <div class="capa">
                        <h2>Lavender</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

estoy estudiando recién CSS, pero creo que el problema esta en el position.  Para la imagen es relative y para la capa es absoluto (pero absoluto respecto de la etiqueta contenedora, no de la imagen y por eso se desborda).
Quizás te valga mirar este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLet5o2ecE8&t=36s

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo tomaré en cuenta!! Yo también estoy estudiando recién CSS, por eso tengo dificultad. Te dejaré saber cualquier avance. Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).